# Undefined value, variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am not sure why I am getting `undefined` in my console. I read about scope variables and learn that defining a variable outside of a scope should make that variable accessible outside of a particular function scope.
Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
const history = createHistory();
const location = history.location;
let loc;
const listen = history.listen((location) => {
  loc = `${location.search}${location.hash}`;
  return loc;
})
console.log(loc);
```

My console is logging `undefined`

Comment: Be careful, `location` is a global variable on the `window`, which you can access by `window.location` or even just `location`.

Answer (score 1):

That is beacuse you are logging `loc` before it has been assigned a value. It is only initialized so its value is `undefined`. It will be assigned value when callback passed to listen will be called. To log correct value you need to change you code to:

```
const history = createHistory();
const location = history.location;
let loc;
const listen = history.listen((location) => {
  loc = `${location.search}${location.hash}`;
  console.log(loc);
})
```

---

I assume that `listen` is asynchronus, so in this context you can't really return it or use the way you described in your question. But once you are in `listen` callback you can pass that value to some other callback. Please see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more explanation and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The problem here is that I want to use `loc` outside of the `listen` function. As of now i only have a console.log for simplification. But what I want to do is once I assign a value to `log` inside `listen`, I want to use `loc` outside of listed with that value. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of `console.log(loc);` that variable is undefined.

As this function

```
(location) => { loc = `${location.search}${location.hash}`; }
```

will run after it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the history.listen method is only called when the location changes. The history.listen(...) call declares the code that should be called when the history changes, but that code hasn't run yet at that point.

In pseudocode, here is what you have instructed:

- Declare some constants and a variable
- Register some code to be run when the history changes
- Printed out the value of the (still uninitialized) variable to the console

This might be closer to what you mean:

```
const history = createHistory();
const location = history.location;
let loc;

const listen = history.listen((location) => {
  loc = `${location.search}${location.hash}`;
  console.log(loc);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, but as the rest said, `loc` variable won't be assigned a value until you change the location and therefore the listen method is executed. Until then, its value will be `undefined`. Also, why do you want to have the `listen` variable, that gets  the returned value of `loc` when you already have declared it on top of your code?